# Subtract two date field values and get the minutes

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, minute

I have below `TEMP_PROCESS_MONITOR` table which has `ALERT_TIMESTAMP` column which has date data type.The `TIMEOUT` column has Number data type and it consist of Minutes values. I want to subtract the Current date with the `ALERT_TIMESTAMP` field and get the minutes and then compare this minutes with `TIMEOUT` field in the below select query. 
`TEMP_PROCESS_MONITOR` table:
[image]

And the condition should be for example like this:

```
(CURRENT_TIMESTMAP - ALERT_TIMESTAMP) > TIMEOUT
```

So i have to remove the Where condition from the below query and put the condition which i have mentioned above:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEMP_PROCESS_MONITOR WHERE IS_DOWN = 1;
```

Comment: So, what exactly is the question?

Comment: The question is i have select query in which i have to remove the mention condition where IS_DOWN=1 and put the condition which i have mentioned in my question. So the select query should be for example like this: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEMP_PROCESS_MONITOR WHERE (CURRENT_TIMESTMAP - ALERT_TIMESTAMP) > TIMEOUT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get current date with seconds in date format you may use `SYSDATE` SQL function.
Date subtraction gives number of days (with fraction) as a result.
So you need either translate this number to minutes:

```
(SYSDATE - ALERT_TIMESTAMP)*24*60 > TIMEOUT
```

or translate timeout to days:

```
(SYSDATE - ALERT_TIMESTAMP) > TIMEOUT/(24*60)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the answer how its returning the minutes from this two datetime fields ? I am getting one row returned now if i use your first condition and as menitoned in my table its returning the first row in which TIMEOUT has 120 and ALERT_TIMESTAMP has 17.06.15 16:29:33 value.

Comment: What does *24*60 means ?